# Eclipse Luna can't resolve c++11 function "stoi"

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, gcc, eclipse-luna

I'm trying to use stoi and stod but eclipse won't let me. I'm using eclipse Lina (on Win 8.1) with minGW latest version.

Here is what I tried:

- `C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous -> Other Flags`. Put -std=c++11
- `C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Symbols -> GNU C++`. Click "Add..." and paste `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` (ensure to append and prepend two underscores) into "Name" and leave "Value" blank.
- Go to `Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Path and Symbols -> Tab [Symbols]`. Add the symbol : `__cplusplus` with the value `201103L`
- `Window->Properties-> C/C++ -> Setting -> Build-> Discovery Options-> CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Setting` and added the "-std=c++11" flag to the invocation arguments there. The linse is now `${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} -E -P -v -dD -std=c++11 "${INPUTS}"`
- `Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Dialect` Put `-std=c++11` into text box entitled other dialect flags or select `ISO C++11` from the Language standard drop down.
- `-std=c++11` flag is on in the `CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings` entry at the providers tab under `Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.` It is also the only checked entry.

I rebuild the indexer and the project itself after every step I try. No help.
I have zero idea what else to do...

*PS I have included std and string libraries and using namespace std

Comment: sanity check: you did `#include <string>` right?

Comment: Yes, I wrote in the edit and fot some reasone it didn't show

Answer (score 0):

`stoi` and `stod` are *not* standard functions. Try using `boost` for this functionality.

Edit: I guess c++11 did include these functions. Are you making sure to use `std::`?
Also, make sure you're using at least gcc 4.7

I've heard about eclipse having trouble with c++11 standards before. Barring all of these not working, are you able to use `boost::lexical_cast`?

Comment: I am using the namespace itself (tried with :: too) and my gcc version is 5.something

Answer (score 0):

The following method works for me.

Go to Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Path and Symbols -> Tab [Symbols]--> GNU c++.

Add the symbol :

__cplusplus with the value 201103L